# How to add tessdata relatively? or use the folder from reference?

Tags: c#, vb.net

[image]

Based on the picture above is how I referenced the tessdata folder from my project. But it returns an error,
`Unable to load unicharset file ./tessdata/\eng.unicharset`
Note that `eng.unicharset` is present on the folder.

Comment: Does it load the file if you provide the exact path such as `D:\....\eng.charset` of the file?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want that or does it matter during build? I mean, when you make an "msi" file?

Comment: No, you should use a relative path, but I am wondering if your slashes should be the other way around? If you are on a Windows OS, try `ocr.Init(@".\tessdata\","eng",false)` (and perhaps leave the slash at the end off: `ocr.Init(@".\tessdata","eng",false)`)

Comment: @4ndy I'm on Windows, I have tried that..still unable to locate the file.

Comment: Can you log or write to console the parsed path of *./tessdata/* prior to referencing it?  Just to verify the path?  What about adding the **unicharset** file to the project and re-running?

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Copy, paste and format as code.

Comment: @Mary I'm just trying to show the image as reference of the project structure.